# Pushing back the same D3DXVECTOR3 with slightly modified values into a vector multiple times

Tags: c++, vector, directx

In my program I have a vector containing D3DXVECTOR3 variables. As might be inferred the vector is to contain multiple D3DXVECTOR3 vectors. However  for efficiency's sake I only have a single D3DXVECTOR3 variable whose values of x,y and z I change before pushing back into the vector container multiple times and I was just wondering whether its possible to have a single D3DXVECTOR3 variable which you update multiple times before pushing back into your vector container OR do you have to declare a new D3DXVECTOR3 variable for however many vectors you want the parent vector to contain?

Currently the code looks like this:

```
vector<D3DXVECTOR3> gradients;
D3DXVECTOR3 singleGrad;                     

singleGrad.x = 1.0;
singleGrad.y = 1.0;
singleGrad.z = 0.0;
gradients.push_back(singleGrad);
singleGrad.x = -1.0;                        
gradients.push_back(singleGrad);
singleGrad.x = 1.0;
singleGrad.y = -1.0;
gradients.push_back(singleGrad);
singleGrad.x = -1.0;
singleGrad.y = -1.0;
singleGrad.z = 0.0;
gradients.push_back(singleGrad);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your conception of efficiency is completely wrong when you consider you do not even reserve memory in your vector and then have potential underlying resize with copy of the previous values.

You should consider writing code easy to read and optimize where it will really matters :

```
std::vector<D3DXVECTOR3> gradients;
gradients.reserve(4);
gradients.push_back({ 1.f, 1.f, 0.f});
gradients.push_back({-1.f, 1.f, 0.f});
gradients.push_back({ 1.f,-1.f, 0.f});
gradients.push_back({-1.f,-1.f, 0.f});
```

If you are concern with code size, factorize with loop.

```
std::vector<D3DXVECTOR3> gradients;
gradients.reserve(4);
float const signs[] { 1.f, -1.f };
for( int v{};v!=2;++v )
    for( int u{};u!=2;++u )
        gradients.push_back({signs[u],signs[v], 0.f});
```